What part of speech is "likewise" here?
Take the opening line from Joe Sachs's translation of Nicomachean Ethics (emphasis mine):

Every art and every inquiry, and likewise every action and choice, seems to aim at some good, and hence it has been beautifully said that the good is that at which all things aim.


What part of speech is likewise?

I could replace likewise with also. Would that be the same part of speech?


Merriam-Webster says both likewise and also are adverbs. In that case:

What is it modifying?


To me, likewise seems to be acting more like a correlative conjunction with and, helping to join the four nouns (art, inquiry, action, and choice) acting as the subject. If it's an adverb, then it'd have to modify the verb seems, like how hence modifies has been said. But that doesn't feel right.

Looks adverbial to me. Same as He did it in the same way, which doesn't exactly mean the same as He did it also or ...too.

A synonym would be "similarly". The "ly" suffix marks this as an adverb.

Yes, likewise=in the same way. Translations are not great places to see usage.

This is not the prototypical verb-modifying adverb usage. 'Every A[,] and likewise/similarly every B[,] seems to V.' The comparison, Ø = 'likewise' or 'in the same way', is made between   'Every A seems to V' & Ø 'Every B seems to V'. That is, the statements in two independent clauses are brought into comparison.

It does modify “seems”, but only when applied to one of the conjoined subject phrases. You can paraphrase the sentence as “Every art and every inquiry seems […], and every action and choice seems likewise”, where it should be much less controversial.

It’s still just an adverb
The Oxford English Dictionary provides these two senses with three subsenses for likewise, which it classifies only as an adverb:


1. (c1443–) In a like manner. Now usually in to do likewise: to do the same. Cf. in like wise adv. In to do likewise after Luke 10:37.
2.a. (?1483–)  Used to introduce a point similar or related to one just made: in the same way; similarly, equally.
2.b. (1509–) In addition; also, as well, too. Used only when there is a degree of similarity or relatedness between what is additional and what has already been mentioned.
2.c. (1946–) Used conversationally to reciprocate or indicate agreement with a sentiment expressed by another person.


Yours is not the first sense, so it’s one of the second sense’s three subsenses, almost certainly 2.b.
Now it’s interesting that you should mention also and correlative conjunction pairs. That’s because for sense 3 of also adverb, the OED draws specific attention to a case quite similar to yours, the pair not only..but also:


(Old English–) Expressing amplification: as a further point, item, or circumstance tending in the same direction; further, in addition, besides, as well, too. Cf. eke adv., too adv. I.1.
not only..but also: see but conj. C.III.11b.ii, only adv. A.3.


The cited but conj. sense is:

III.11.b.ii. (c1384–) After not only, not merely. Frequently strengthened by the addition of also (not only, but also). Cf. only adv. A.3.

So just as with but also where adding the also to the conjunction but “strengthens” its conjunction, it seems reasonable to infer that with and likewise when you add the adverb likewise to the conjunction and, this  after the same fashion “strengthens” its own respective conjunction.
This shows that at least as far as the OED accounts for these things, adding an adverb after a coördinating conjunction to create some sort of paired correlative conjunction or an “intensified” or ”strengthened” conjunction does not somehow change the fundamental word-class of that adverb into a conjunction in its own right.
And intensifying adverbs should not be considered “very” new concepts. :)

So with regard to (3), does this mean that likewise is modifying the conjunction and?

@kviLL I'm not sure that's necessarily the right way to look at it.  It's emphasizing that what's true for the first element is similarly true for the second element. It feels like it's providing a particular kind of focus on that second element that the and conjunction is coordinating, is connecting to. Here the second element is all of every action and choice, so that's the syntactic constituent that likewise is focusing on or intensifying in the context of the conjunction and.

@kviLL I should add that you may get a different answer if you run that sentence through a dependency parser as you will get if you run it through a constituency parser. No matter whether you write it as also or likewise or similarly, the simplistic dependency parser tries to apply the adverb to the verb, because that's really all it knows how to do here. But the more sophisticated constituency parser recognizes that the also/likewise/similarly actually applies to the NP following it using a connector relation, not to the verb.
